# Is it OK to have variables in a Lightning Component Helper

Tags: lightning-aura-components, helper

I'm working on a drag + drop application in Lightning. I've worked up my solution by having a wrapper component, FormDraggableElement, which goes around anything that I want to be able to drag around or drop onto. I want the wrapper to do two things:

- Abstract away the difficulties posed by dropping onto a droppable inside a droppable (events are fired for both, I only care about the inner one)
- Fire a Lightning event with both the dragged component and the target component are available (not their DOM nodes, the components)

To do this, I've written a helper which uses some variables to keep track of timing and which components are in use:

```
({
    lastTimestamp : {
        dragEnter : 0,
        drop : 0
    },
    draggedComponent : null,
    dragEnter : function(component, event) {
        if(event.timeStamp > this.lastTimestamp.dragEnter) {
            console.log('dragEnter: ' + event.currentTarget.dataset.developername);
            $A.util.addClass(component, 'drop-target');
            this.lastTimestamp.dragEnter = event.timeStamp;
            this.draggedComponent = component;
        }
    },
    drop : function(component, event) {
        if(event.timeStamp > this.lastTimestamp.drop) {
            var cmpEvent = component.getEvent('drop');
            cmpEvent.setParams({
                'developerName': event.currentTarget.dataset.developername,
                'targetComponent': component,
                'draggedComponent': this.draggedComponent
            });
            cmpEvent.fire();
            $A.util.removeClass(component, 'drop-target');
            this.lastTimestamp.drop = event.timeStamp;
        }
    }
})
```

This seems to work, but I've been unable to find any docs which say you can add variables to your helper in this way. I understand (and am using) the fact that a single helper instance is shared between all instances of the component.

So, my question is: Is this use of variables in the helper acceptable? Do we think it's likely to be disallowed by SF in the future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't store data in the helper. While it's not explicitly forbidden, the documentation does not specify that it is safe to store data in the helper, so you should make no assumptions that it is until/unless the documentation states that this is an appropriate use of the helper. Personally, I'd expect that they'll probably lock this down eventually. Typically, you'll want at least two components; one for the dropzone and one for the draggable elements. I wrote a [gist](https://gist.github.com/brianmfear/fb13ac4781c79fad6495ef7dc1676f4f) that does this without the extra layer of components, but this is how I'd recommend you go about doing it. If you need cross-DropZone functionality, you'll want to store that data in a parent component so that all DropZone components can communicate with each other.

Comment: OK, noted. I can make an outer layer handle what the helper-sharing was doing. I wish I could use something as simple as your drag+drop, but I'm building something a bit like the App Builder - you drag and drop form elements together to build a custom input form where the layout is stored in JSON. So, everything can be a draggable and a target - and the form needs to work without being draggable outside the builder. I make the distinction by using the FormDraggableElement as a decorator (in the pattern sense).

Comment: @Aidan Yeah, I had a feeling you might say something like that. Orchestrating the drag-drop logic in a parent component will simplify things in the long run.

Answer (score 3):

Someone from the Aura team might chime in with a more definitive answer; however, I think that helper variables are acceptable in certain situations. You have to be careful though as helpers are singletons.

In your example above, this works so long as you only have 1 FormDraggableElement.cmp. Suppose you had two completely separate drag and drop instances, they would both share the helper so you could potentially see some weird side effects from shared variables getting mixed up. This is a problem as old as javascript and there are a lot of solutions (name spacing, etc) available to work around that.

Drag and drop is a bit of one-off because users probably won't be dragging and dropping 2 different things simultaneously. Any components sharing the helper variables there will just take turns using them. In a perfect world, lightning would prefer you to cmp.set('v.draggedComponent', draggedCmp); In my experience though, it's often not worth the overhead and complexity of sending the components into the valueProvider blackhole - what with locker service and all. I'd probably just put a namespace id on the component and have the helper store keep track of different components in a map on the helper.

TLDR; When choosing where to persist data in lightning. Determine if ALL the instance of that component on the page need the same data - Helper is OK. Else use component.set()

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Hopefully someone from Aura will be able to comment, but it's useful to know I'm not the only one using this. I'm going to treat drag+drop as global, so I'm perfectly happy with my variable being shared. In fact, my design relies on it.